# Javascript activex dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, activex

I have the following question:
I am trying to use a dwf viewer application, this is backuped by an activex that permits to view dwf files when the plugin is installed.

Usually one would use this plugin like this:

```
<object
classid = "clsid:A662DA7E-CCB7-4743-B71A-D817F6D575DF"
codebase = "http://www.autodesk.com/global/dwfviewer/installer/DwfViewerSetup.cab#version=6,0,0,200"
ID = "Eview"
width = "500"
height = "500"
border="0"></object>
```

then just call functions like this:

```
Eview.Viewer.ExecuteCommand("BLACKANDWHITE");
etc..
```

The thing is I am now creating the object in an Iframe by server side:

```
<iframe id="dwfFrame" name="dwfFrame" src="plot.aspx" width="100%" height="100%" onload="initDWF()"/>
```

in plot.aspx I write the dynamic dwf, and then when loading the iframe, the activex is opened and the dwf shown correctly.

```
   // Now output the resulting DWF.

    OutputReaderContent(Response, byteReader);
```

The problem is on my page I am unable to make Javascript calls cause I do not have a reference to the object, I tried issuing them to the Iframe but it doesn't work. Like this:

```
dwfViewer = document.dwfFrame;
dwfViewer.Viewer.ExecuteCommand("BLACKANDWHITE");
dwfViewer.ExecuteCommand("BLACKANDWHITE");
```

I beleive this is because the iframe is not the instancied activex object, is there anyway I could get ahold of this object so I can work on it?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var dwfFrameDoc = parent.dwfFrame.document;
var dwfViewer = dwfFrameDoc.getElementById('Eview');
```

I don't play around with multiple frames too often, but that is how you would address another frame. It shouldn't matter that the frame in question is an `iframe`. Each frame has its own `window` object. The `document` is a property of that object. `parent` refers to the parent of the current `window` or to itself if it is already the top level.

`document.dwfFrame` would get you the element whose id is dwfFrame, which is not the same as the window object of the iframe. Even if it were, doing `dwfViewer.ExecuteCommand('BLACKANDWHITE');` would try to call `ExecuteCommand` as a method of the iframe's window, not the viewer object.